# Material-UI: Positioning top Drawer under top App bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to place a top drawer under my top app bar for navigation purposes. According to the API documentation Drawer has all the properties of the Modal component, when variant="temporary". The property "disablePortal" should lead to the desired behaviour, but it doesn't work:

> The children will be under the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

What I tried so far:

- set disablePortal in Drawer
- set disablePortal via ModalProps property of the Drawer
- creat a ref and set container property of the Drawer with the current value of it

What I do not want:

- Use Accordion in top app bar, as I think this is not the right solution
- Tweak z-indexes
- Use some height hacks (position drawer with the height value of top app bar)

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/drawer/

Minimal working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cache-7y6qmv

```
import { AppBar, Box, Drawer, IconButton, Toolbar } from "@mui/material";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showNavigation, setShowNavigation] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Box>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={() => setShowNavigation((prev) => !prev)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        anchor="top"
        open={showNavigation}
        onClose={() => setShowNavigation(false)}
        disablePortal
      >
        Test
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that you think `disablePortal` has something to do with how the drawer will be positioned. It does not. It merely controls where the DOM elements are located within the DOM structure. It does not change the visual location of the elements from a user's perspective.

Comment: The same is true of the `container` prop -- it does not impact the visual location, only the DOM hierarchy location. This can have visual effects due to impacting CSS inheritance or by being in an ancestor element that is hidden or overflow CSS could prevent it from displaying beyond its parent, but neither the `container` prop or `disablePortal` impact the visual location of the drawer.

Comment: Why is DOM position not the same as visual position? DOM is parsed and elements are rendered, no? If you can't change the visual position of the component: What is the purpose of these two props?

Comment: `Drawer` uses [position: fixed](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.8.2/packages/mui-material/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L83) and therefore its visual location is independent of its location in the DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and it worked:

```
import { AppBar, Box, Drawer, IconButton, Toolbar } from "@mui/material";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { useState } from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    position: "relative !important",
    "& .MuiBackdrop-root": {
      position: "relative !important",
      height: "100vh"
    }
  },
  paper: {
    position: "absolute !important"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const [showNavigation, setShowNavigation] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={() => setShowNavigation((prev) => !prev)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        anchor="top"
        open={showNavigation}
        onClose={() => setShowNavigation(false)}
        disablePortal
        classes={{
          paper: classes.paper,
          root: classes.root,
        }}
      >
        Test
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-top-drawer-disableportal-bug-forked-ic8ql9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Doesn't it set ALL paper components to position=absolute?

Comment: @IgorGonak yes it would only for Paper components under that one Drawer component. It depends on what you put inside the drawer really, but I didn't think having child Paper components inside the Drawer parent component was in the scope of the question